# Matlab, operator A\B

Tags: matlab, operators

What is the result of the operation A\B, where A(1, m) and B (1, m)?

In the manual it is written:

```
A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations A*x= B.
```

So it means x = inv (A'*A)*A'*B? However, the matrix A'*A is singular...

Let us suppose:

```
A=[1 2 3]
B=[6 7 6]
A\B

0         0         0
0         0         0
2.0000    2.3333    2.0000
```

If ve use MLS:

```
C = inv (A'*A)   singular matrix
C = pinv(A'*A)

0.0051    0.0102    0.0153
0.0102    0.0204    0.0306
0.0153    0.0306    0.0459

D= C*A'*B

0.4286    0.5000    0.4286
0.8571    1.0000    0.8571
1.2857    1.5000    1.2857
```

So results A\B and inv (A'*A)*A'*B are different...

Comment: The documentation of `pinv` contains some discussion on the difference between `pinv` and \.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My MATLAB (R2010b) says quite a lot about what `A\B` does:

> `mldivide(A,B)` and the equivalent `A\B` perform matrix left division
>   (back slash). `A` and `B`    must be matrices that have the same number of
>   rows, unless `A` is a scalar, in which case `A\B` performs element-wise
>   division — that is, `A\B = A.\B`.
>
> If `A` is a square matrix, `A\B` is roughly the same as `inv(A)*B`, except
>   it is computed in a different way. If `A` is an `n`-by-`n` matrix and `B` is a
>   column vector with `n` elements, or a matrix with several such columns,
>   then `X = A\B` is the solution to the equation `AX = B`. A warning message
>   is displayed if `A` is badly scaled or nearly singular.
>
> If `A` is an `m`-by-`n` matrix with `m ~= n` and `B` is a column vector with `m`
>   components, or a matrix with several such columns, then `X = A\B` is the
>   solution in the least squares sense to the under- or overdetermined
>   system of equations `AX = B`. In other words, `X` minimizes `norm(A*X - B)`,
>   the length of the vector `AX - B`. The rank `k` of `A` is determined from
>   the QR decomposition with column pivoting. The computed solution `X` has
>   at most `k` nonzero elements per column. If `k < n`, this is usually not
>   the same solution as `x = pinv(A)*B`, which returns a least squares
>   solution.
>
> `mrdivide(B,A)` and the equivalent `B/A` perform matrix right division
>   (forward slash). `B` and `A` must have the same number of columns.
>
> If `A` is a square matrix, `B/A` is roughly the same as `B*inv(A)`. If `A` is
>   an `n`-by-`n` matrix and `B` is a row vector with `n` elements, or a matrix
>   with several such rows, then `X = B/A` is the solution to the equation
>   `XA = B` computed by Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting. A
>   warning message is displayed if `A` is badly scaled or nearly singular.
>
> If `B` is an `m`-by-`n` matrix with `m ~= n` and `A` is a column vector with `m`
>   components, or a matrix with several such columns, then `X = B/A` is the
>   solution in the least squares sense to the under- or overdetermined
>   system of equations `XA = B`.

Comment: @ FakeDIY. Thanks, but I had already read before I posted my question. However, the case three it is not clear for me...

Answer (score 3):

`x = inv (A'*A)*A'*B` goes for *over determined* systems (i.e. which feature `A` as an `n x m` matrix with `n>m`; in these circumstances `A'A` is invertible).

In your case you have an *under determined* system.

---

Thus, what may happen?

*My opinion, although you can check, at least in your case*:

when you do `A\B` matlab solves an optimization problem in the inverse sense w.r.t. the usual least squares, that is

```
 X = argmin_{X \in S} ||X||,
```

where `S` is the set of solutions. In other words, it gives you the solution of the system having minimum L^2 norm. (Consider that you can handle the problem by hands, at least in your case).